# Problem when creating arduino library with dependencies

Tags: arduino, dependencies, libraries, can-bus, arduino-c++

I have an `ArduinoCanUtils.h` header file and a `ArduinoCanUtils.cpp` source file, organized in the following directory tree:

```
Documents
|---Arduino
|   |---libraries
|       |--- autowp-mcp2515
|       |    |--- other library files
|       |
|       |--- ArduinoCanUtils 
|            |--- ArduinoCanUtils.h
             |--- ArduinoCanUtils.cpp
```

These files make up the *ArduinoCanUtils* library I'm trying to create. The contents of `ArduinoCanUtils.h` are as follows:

```
#ifndef ArduinoCanUtils_h
#define ArduinoCanUtils_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <mcp2515.h>


class ArduinoCanUtils
{
  public:
    ArduinoCanUtils();
    uint32_t createCanMsgCanId(uint8_t priorityLevel, uint8_t activityCode, uint8_t destinationAddress, uint8_t originAddress);
    uint8_t getPriorityLevelFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId);
    uint8_t getActivityCodeFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId);
    uint8_t getDestinationAddressFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId);
    uint8_t getOriginAddressFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId);
    void setAllCanMsgDataToZero(struct can_frame &canMsg);

};

#endif
```

While the contents of `ArduinoCanUtils.cpp` are as follows:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <mcp2515.h> 
#include "ArduinoCanUtils.h"

ArduinoCanUtils::ArduinoCanUtils(){}

uint32_t ArduinoCanUtils::createCanMsgCanId(uint8_t priorityLevel, uint8_t activityCode, uint8_t destinationAddress, uint8_t originAddress)
{
  uint32_t canId = 0;
  canId = canId | originAddress;
  canId = canId | destinationAddress << 8;
  canId = canId | ((uint32_t) activityCode) << 16;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){bitWrite(canId, 26 + i, bitRead(priorityLevel, i));}  
  bitWrite(canId, 31, 1);
  return canId;
}

uint8_t ArduinoCanUtils::getPriorityLevelFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId){
  uint8_t priorityLevel = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){bitWrite(priorityLevel, i, bitRead(canId, 26 + i));}  
  return priorityLevel;
}

uint8_t ArduinoCanUtils::getActivityCodeFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId){
  uint8_t activityCode = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){bitWrite(activityCode, i, bitRead(canId, 16 + i));}  
  return activityCode;
}

uint8_t ArduinoCanUtils::getDestinationAddressFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId){
  uint8_t destinationAddress = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){bitWrite(destinationAddress, i, bitRead(canId, 8 + i));} 
  return destinationAddress;
}

uint8_t ArduinoCanUtils::getOriginAddressFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId){
  uint8_t originAddress = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){bitWrite(originAddress, i, bitRead(canId, i));}  
  return originAddress;
}

void ArduinoCanUtils::setAllCanMsgDataToZero(struct can_frame &canMsg){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){canMsg.data[i] = 0;}
}
```

As you can see, the function `setAllCanMsgDataToZero` requires the type `struct can_frame` for its argument. This type is defined over in the 3rd-party library **autowp-mcp2515** (link: https://github.com/autowp/arduino-mcp2515.git), but when I try to use that function in the following test script:

```
#include <mcp2515.h> 
#include <ArduinoCanUtils.h>

MCP2515 mcp2515Global(10); 
struct can_frame canMsg = {.can_id = 0, .can_dlc = 8, .data = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}; 
ArduinoCanUtils canUtils;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

uint32_t a = canUtils.createCanMsgCanId(1, 1, 2, 1);
uint8_t b = canUtils.getActivityCodeFromCanMsgCanId(a);
canUtils.setAllCanMsgDataToZero(&canMsg);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I get the following error log after compiling (see image):

[image]

Interestingly, all other functions from my library seem to work fine, only that function poses a problem.

I made sure to include all necessary dependencies. Also, the other functions aside from `setAllCanMsgDataToZero` seem to work fine. I verified that I'm declaring the struct can_fame correctly but I don't know why it keeps raising that error. help would be very much appreciated. This is my first time writing a library for Arduino and I tried searching the internet but found little help. I hope you can help me.

Comment: C++ 101: global space is for variable declaration and class instance creation, not for calling class method to execute code. So move those execution into a function (i.e. your setup() or loop()).

Comment: "I tried searching the internet, but found little help". There are tutorial such as [Write a library for Arduino](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/contributions/arduino-creating-library-guide/) and [Arduino Library Style Guide](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/contributions/arduino-library-style-guide/).

Comment: By the way, things like `for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){canMsg.data[i] = 0;}` can be done with `memset(canMsg.data,0);` and most of the methods such as the entire function `getPriorityLevelFromCanMsgCanId(uint32_t canId)` can be done with one-liner as `(canId & 0x1c000000) > 26;`(i.e. a pattern of (canId & bit_mask) >> bit_position). Read [Bit Math](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/programming/bit-math/) or simply pick up one of the [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/) and read it.

Comment: -hechug, thank you for your help!. I'll try to respond to each of your comments chronologically:

1) You were right. I moved all the lines where I invoke the CanUtils methods inside void setup() and now the new error is this: 'compilation error: no matching function for call to 'ArduinoCanUtils::setAllCanMsgDataToZero(can_frame*)'. How could I solve it?.

2) I actually followed the example of that link, but it doesn't deal with dependencies.

3) Thx, I'll take it into account, though I prefer readability and intuition over performance in my case, since I'm a noob.

Comment: Your original design is passing function parameter by [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-functions-pass-by-reference/) with &canMsg and now you are passing the parameter by pointer *canMsg.

Comment: @hcheung, thank you again. I looked at the link you posted and I see the error now. I wasn't as familiar with "pass by reference" as I thought. I should do `canUtils.setAllCanMsgDataToZero(canMsg)`  instead of `canUtils.setAllCanMsgDataToZero(&canMsg)` , since in the second case I'm passing the pointer while the function just expects the reference. Thank you. I'm marking the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't as familiar with "pass by reference" as I thought. I should do `canUtils.setAllCanMsgDataToZero(canMsg)` instead of `canUtils.setAllCanMsgDataToZero(&canMsg)`, since in the second case I'm passing the pointer while the function just expects the reference.

It turns out this is not a dependency problem at all.